# Cancel ongoing Service and Job - grails

Tags: grails, service, jobs

I'm just thinking if is it possible to cancel or stop an ongoing service or job? for example I have a code that calls a method in a service and then the user suddenly want to cancel the said operation. is it possible to stop that or roll back the changes made before the service was canceled since it's transactional? Let's say I have this code:

```
class SomeService {
    static transactional = true
    
    def someMethod() {
        //some business logic here 
    
        SomeTriggeredJob.triggerNow((java.util.LinkedHashMap)[params: queriedParams]
    }
}
```

is there a way to cancel this if it's already executing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Let the user send a canceling request;
2. on the server side set a flag in DB or session, to which your job has access to;
3. the job should first of all read that value and depending on it - proceed or cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Set some flag to false if user cancels the process and save the flag in either session or database. While, in the method/job that you are running, put a loop and check every time for the flag. So, if you get false in the flag, don't run the job next time.
For example, if the user cancels set

```
session.cancelFlag = false
```

And in your job, do something like

```
def jobMethod(){
    someLoop.each{
        if(session.cancelFlag){
            Do your work here !
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For cancel a transaction context of one Service you can launch a throw in Service if you need to do this outgoing of the Service you can incapsulate this in a method.

```
serviceExample.doCancel()
```

*"The result is that all methods are wrapped in a transaction and automatic rollback occurs if a method throws a runtime exception (i.e. one that extends RuntimeException) or an Error. The propagation level of the transaction is by default set to PROPAGATION_REQUIRED.
Checked exceptions do not roll back transactions. Even though Groovy blurs the distinction between checked and unchecked exceptions, Spring isn't aware of this and its default behaviour is used, so it's important to understand the distinction between checked and unchecked exceptions."*

[Grails Documentation - Services](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#services)